# .net solution to get files associated with changesets in TFS

Tags: .net, tfs, solution, changeset

I have a .net solution to get a set of changesets into a TFS local workspace that are specified in a config file [values.xml]. Once the files associated to the changesets are downloaded to the local working folder associated with the workspace, I have a separate packaging script that creates a msi out of those files. The .net solution works fine, but usually. The problem arises under the following condition:

Say I have a changeset: C717171 which is associated to a change that I have done on web.config file.
The config file [values.xml] lists this changeset in it which implies that the .net solution has to get this specific changeset into the TFS local workspace after which a separate packaging script will take over.

What actually happens is, the .net solution places all the web.config files that are in the repository along with the one that is required.

```
        var changesets = vcs.QueryHistory(repository, VersionSpec.Latest, 0, RecursionType.Full, null, versionFrom, versionTo, Int32.MaxValue, true, false).Cast<Changeset>();
            Workspace myworkspace = vcs.CreateWorkspace(workspaceName, tfsUser);
            var workingFolder = new WorkingFolder(repository, workspacePath);
            // create WorkingFolder and mapping
            myworkspace.CreateMapping(workingFolder);

            foreach (Changeset changeset in changesets.OrderBy(c => c.ChangesetId))
            {
                var version = new ChangesetVersionSpec(changeset.ChangesetId);

                foreach (Change change in changeset.Changes)
                {
                    myworkspace.Get(new[] { change.Item.ServerItem }, version, RecursionType.Full, GetOptions.Overwrite);
                }
            }
```

I may provide more details if required.

Comment: Is it all web.config files that get downloaded, or just the web.config files that are in the same folder and all subfolders of each 'server item' from each changeset? I would look at your use of RecursionType and see if not using Full corrects the issue.

Comment: All the web.config files get downloaded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to get a single file, you need to use `RecursionType.None`, not `RecursionType.Full`.

When you use `RecursionType.Full` on a path that is a file, you are specifying that you want the file with that name in the specified folder, *and* any files with the same name in subfolders.

So if you specify `$/Project/file.txt`, it will download `$/Project/file.txt` as well as `$/Project/subdir1/file.txt`, `$/Project/subdir2/file.txt`, etc.

Specify `RecursionType.None` to match *exactly* the given path.